# How to fill color outside the circle on google map using Swift?

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want the red circle just have the border (no red in centre) and have the rest outside the circle darkened?

I have a issue about that. Could you help me solve it?

[image: My screen]

Comment: create a view with size of your device's screen, add on top, and clear the center circle.

Answer (score 0):

With google maps for this, you should do the following steps

1. Create a `GMSCircle` object
2. Set stroke color and fill color for the
   circle
3. Set map for the circle object

Example code:

```
let circleCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(9.931233, 76.267303)//change to your center point
let circ = GMSCircle(position: circleCenter, radius: 5000)//radius in meters

circ.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.35, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.05)
circ.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
circ.strokeWidth = 1
circ.map = mapView //your map view in the UI
```